# Atomic-based lock for thread-safe use of elements

Tags: c, openmp, atomic, flush

I want to create a thread-safe routine that executes in parallel (with OpenMP) and accesses several elements. The elements are basically structs with a couple variables and an array. Threads can access these elements from several points. I have multiple (a variable no. of) arrays with pointers to the elements in my program. So, it is possible that one thread T1 access one element E via one array A1, and another thread T2 accesses the same element via another array A2.

What I thought about doing was to create the following structure:

```
//try to use element E in array 1     

#pragma omp flush(array1[E]->lock)
   if(!array1[E]->lock){
      array1[E]->lock = 1;

      ...//use (either read, write or both) element

      array1[E]->lock = 0;
      #pragma omp flush(array1[E]->lock)
   }
```

Is this theoretically safe? I am OK with ignoring elements that are being used by other threads because my algorithm will eventually visit them again. If my if fails, I move forward (I don't want to get stuck till the using thread releases the element).

Comment: Any reason why you are not using C++11 atomic builtins? The `_atomic_compare_exchange_n` builtin will do exactly what you want. [source](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html)

Comment: Your lock isn't atomic, so it's possible that two or more threads will process the same element in parallel. And the first thread to finish with the element will set the lock back to 0, even though other threads are still working. If you're OK with that, too, then I guess it might work, but it's not a lock so much as a hint in that case.

Comment: @CristianoSousa this is C code, not C++.

Comment: @Mgetz this is C code, not C++.

Comment: @pburka Should I use #pragma omp atomic both to write and read? I.e. before    if(!array1[E]->lock) and on both writes?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use OpenMP locks rather than attempting to roll your own?

Comment: @JimCownie This seems much cheaper than an OpenMP, ain't that true?

Comment: @a3mlord I just referred to that specific version because it's the most recent implementation. Starting from GCC 4.3.1 the equivalent function `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` is available: [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)

Comment: @JimCownie is right. Getting locks right is very tricky. Use a library implementation instead of rolling your own. Use `omp_init_lock()`, `omp_test_lock()` and `omp_unset_lock()` instead.